# Incrementar cantidad a variable en redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

tengo un problema de lógica en mi proyecto, necesito cargar en mi estado un arreglo de objetos que contenga algunos productos, la dinámica es la siguiente: Cuando un producto ya esta en lista hay que incrementar la propiedad `cantidad:` en `1`, y si no se encuentra pues agregarlo para obtener el estado de la siguiente manera:

```
[
  {id: 'PROD02', product: 'Banana split', price: '$2,80', cantidad: 1}
  {id: 'PROD01', product: 'Cono doble', price: '$1,25', cantidad: 2}
]
```

Action :

```
export const addItemTicket = (id, product, price, cantidad = 1) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: types.tickedAddNewItem,
      payload: {
        id,
        product,
        price,
        cantidad,
      },
    });
  };
```

Reducer:

```
export const ticketReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.tickedAddNewItem:
      if (state.length == 0) {
      //Cargando el primer artículo
        return [...state, action.payload];
      } else {
      //recorrer el estado para sumar el contador y agregar nuevo item
        let a = [];
        state.forEach((item) => {
          if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
            item.cantidad += action.payload.cantidad;
            a.push(item);
          } else {
            a.push(action.payload);
          }
        });
        return a;
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

La carga de los artículos funciona y se incrementa cuando hago `dispatch` del mismo producto, el problema esta al disparar un producto diferente, el estado de la aplicación se reinicia y toma el estado con el último articulo seleccionado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problema

Estas inicializando un array vacio cada vez que entra en el else. Luego buscas dentro del state, por eso no te falla al añadir una cantidad pero sí al añadir un nuevo item.

Seguramente esto se debe a que has leído/aprendido que no se debe devolver una modificación del state, si no una nueva copia, pero no has terminado de tenerlo claro.

#### Solucion

```
const addNewItem = () => {
const search = state.filter((item) => item.id === action.payload.id);
if (search.length !== 0 ) {
    return state.map((item) => {
    if (item.id === newItem.id) {
        return {...item, cantidad: item.cantidad + action.payload.cantidad}
    }
        return item;
    })
} else {
    return [...state, action.payload];
}};
```

En los casos en los que exista un item coincidente la función deberia utilizar un map para actualizarla, de esta manera además creamos una copia nueva del array así que estamos respetando la inmutabilidad del estado.

En los casos en los que no exista, creamos una copia añadiendo el nuevo item al final del array.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias por la explicación estimado.